# Mapster not mapping

Tags: c#, mapster

I'm using Mapster with DI and I'm trying to map objects that I receive from WS. I was following this guide https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Dependency-Injection#mapping

I register TypeAdapterConfig, and ServiceMapper

```
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
services.AddSingleton(config);
services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
```

Blacklist class contains collection of Cards but webservice returns array of long, that I remap to object.

```
public class BlacklistMapper : IRegister
{
    void IRegister.Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<long, Internal.BlacklistCard>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Cuid, source => source);

        config.NewConfig<SzWebService.BlackList, Internal.Blacklist>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Id, source => source.iBlacklistId)
            .Map(dest => dest.Crc, source => source.iBlackListCRC)
            .Map(dest => dest.Cards, source => source.lCuid);
    }
}
```

Inject mapper in the constuctor

```
 private readonly IMapper _mapper;

 public Service(IMapper mapper)
 {
     _logger = logger;
 }
```

And finally call it like so

```
_mapper.Map<Blacklist>(response.mBlackListData)
```

The result is always object with default values

Comment: Just update the library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1 - Create the configuration via implementing `IRegister`**

```
public class BlacklistMapper : IRegister
{
    void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<SzWebService.BlackList, Internal.Blacklist>()
            .Map(...)
            .Map(...);
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - Register the configuration**

You can either register the configuration explicitly:

```
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();

// Explicitly apply a specific configuration
config.Apply(new BlackListMapper());

services.AddSingleton(config);
services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
```

or let Mapster scan your assemblies for `IRegister` implementations:

```
// Scan & apply IRegisters automatically.
config.Scan(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: Couple of problems with your solutions:
1.  When creating mapper method Register prompts error : Cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

2.  Interface IRegister does not contain method Register with empty parameters

Comment: yeeaap, fixed ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Worked beautifully on my first attempt